# How CQL3 differs from CQL2 and Thrift?

Tags: nosql, cassandra, thrift, cql, cql3

"Compact storage stores an entire row in a single column on disk instead of storing each non-primary key column in a column that corresponds to one column on disk. Using compact storage prevents you from adding new columns that are not part of the PRIMARY KEY."

I can not understand the above statement, is it even true?!

Reference: http://www.edwardcapriolo.com/roller/edwardcapriolo/entry/legacy_tables

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/thrift-to-cql3, it explains most of it.